# MySQL now() is 1 hour behind

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get all the votes from TODAY THE CURRENT , and I have almost achieved that with the following mysql query, but there's one problem.

This code gets me the votes from today:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE `when` > CURRENT_DATE
```

but when inserting into mysql using `now()` the now() is 1 hour behind my timezone (Europe/London) how can I fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: Set the timezone on the server

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-time-zone-of-mysql

Comment: Unknown or incorrect time zone?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to [populate your timezone tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time-zone-support.html#time-zone-installation).  If you are on linux, you can do so by running the following command :

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql
```

You may need to know your root password.  You then can run the following query as root :

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Europe/London';
```

Comment: That is why you need to populate your timezone tables.  Did you do that step?

Comment: Didn't work for me, after setting ``time_zone`` to "Europe/Berlin", ``NOW()`` is still 1 hour behind. Edit: Nevermind, the timezone in the docker container running MySQL was also incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'America/New_York';
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html