# Wrong time retrived in Thymeleaf + Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, datetime, thymeleaf

I am listing a table that is stored in a MySQL BBDD and I don't know why the DateTime field is showing with +1 hour when printed in the Thymeleaf view.

This is the code of the table where I retrieve the info:

```
    <a th:href="@{/new}">Agreagar Nuevo</a>
        <table border="1">
            <thead style="background-color: #5BA5EA">
                <tr>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Apellidos</th>
                    <th>Tlf.</th>                   
                    <th>Tratamiento</th>
                    <th>Doctor</th>
                    <th>Cita</th>
                    <th>Acción</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr th:each="p:${lista_pacientes}">
                    <td th:text="${p.nombre_pac}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${p.apellidos_pac}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${p.tlf_pac}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${p.tratamiento_pac}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${p.doctor_pac}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${#dates.format(p.cita_pac, 'EEEEE, dd/MMMMM/yyyy - HH:mm')}"> </td>
                    <td>
                    <a th:onclick="eliminar([[${p.id_pac}]])" href="#">Borrar</a>
                    <a th:href="@{/listar/}+${p.id_pac}">Modificar</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

And here you can see how that database record is stored in MySql and how the filed date is being printed in the view with +1 hour:

[image: Stored Date in MySQL vs printed Date]

I have tried to change the time zone in MySQL to many different values but it didn't work:
`SET time_zone = "+00:00";`

Thanks

Comment: MySQL & jdbc connector version?

Comment: I don't know specifically how to check the "MySQL & JDBC connector version". These are the dependencies of JPA and MySQL I  added to my pom.xml:   
  
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
 

   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>

Comment: And these are the appliation.properties related to JDBC and MySQL drivers: spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

Comment: You need to set your timezone. you can check similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32150292/mysql-now-is-1-hour-behind

Comment: there is different default behavior to session time zone for jdbc connector since 8.0.23  compared to previous version

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this post can help anyone else: I have solved it by deleting the parameter `?serverTimezone=UTC` when linking the database in the application.properties file:

[image]